# iOS following links on hidden layer

Tags: ios, css, anchor

Here's my fiddle:
*Updated to look nicer: http://jsfiddle.net/fmYpE/1/

```
<div class="block">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/240/240" alt="Kitty" />
    <div class="block-overlay">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="//placekitten.com/10/10">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="//placekitten.com/10/10">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="//placekitten.com/10/10">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="//placekitten.com/10/10">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
.block { position: relative; }

.block-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
}

.block:hover > .block-overlay { opacity: 1; }
```

In iOS, and potentially other touch devices, if you tap on the image where a link is hidden the link will be registered as a click and you'll be redirected.

I need a way to prevent this from happening somehow. In my actual code I have a square image and hidden below it you'll see user data from a social sharing website: username, avatar, status update etc.

These are full of links. I'd like to be able to tap the image and have the overlay div transition position:absolute over the image then be able to tap/click the links and not follow them before the transition has completed.

I've tried a combination of pseudo classes, :focus, :active, also tried with Modernizr, .touch, .no-touch.

I stumbled across this article here but they only spoke of static text, not links...http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/ (Scroll to the Conclusion paragraph)

Any help is always very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague made me aware of the CSS property: pointer-events.

I was able to set the overlay div with pointer-events: none. With a few lines of jQuery I set pointer-events back to auto with a slight delay to accomodate the css transition.

Works great.